# Use Overriden method

Tags: java, class, methods, overriding

I am wondering, how in this example:

```
public class Test
{
    public int getA()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public static class Test2 extends Test
    {
        @Override
        public int getA()
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test2 a = new Test2();
        System.out.println(a.getA());
    }
```

Can i get 1 as result?
Is there any way to do it? Getting Method of Test would be useful for me.

Comment: That's the basis of polymorphism. You would need to write `Test a = new Test();` to get what you want... You should probably explain the scenario in which you need that behaviour: there probably is a better way...

Comment: Don't override if you want to access both the base class and inherited implementations. Maybe you want `Test` to have a method with a different signature that does what `getA()` does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to get 1 when the getA() for Test2 returns 2 as per your specification? Seems counter-intuitive. No, there is no way because returning 2 instead of 1 is the point of overriding in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thanks all i wanted to know. Thanks for fast answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 1 as a result you should be instantiating `Test` instead of `Test2`

```
Test a = new Test();
System.out.println(a.getA());
```